# ThriftDB Rest API how to get matches for range of values?

Tags: api

I am trying to pull all hacker news comments matching:

- created in last 24 hours,
- with more than 10 points (for example)

With the following query:

[http://api.thriftdb.com/api.hnsearch.com/items/_search?pretty_print=true&filter[fields][create_ts]=[NOW-100HOURS%20TO%20NOW]&filter[fields][points]=10](http://api.thriftdb.com/api.hnsearch.com/items/_search?pretty_print=true&filter%5Bfields%5D%5Bcreate_ts%5D=%5BNOW-100HOURS%20TO%20NOW%5D&filter%5Bfields%5D%5Bpoints%5D=10)

The `filter[fields][points]=10` gives me all items matching exactly 10 points, but not the ones with more than 10 points. How do I get all items with more than 10 points?

The [doc to the ThirftDB Rest API is here](http://www.thriftdb.com/documentation/rest-api/search-api) but I just don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query syntax seems similar to Solr (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax):

[http://api.thriftdb.com/api.hnsearch.com/items/_search?pretty_print=true&filter[fields][create_ts]=[NOW-100HOURS TO NOW]&filter[queries][]=points:[10+TO+*]](http://api.thriftdb.com/api.hnsearch.com/items/_search?pretty_print=true&filter%5Bfields%5D%5Bcreate_ts%5D=%5BNOW-100HOURS%20TO%20NOW%5D&filter%5Bqueries%5D%5B%5D=points%3a%5B10%20TO%20%2a%5D)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea why the same request with added &filter[fields][type]=[comment]  does not work ?  The doc is here: http://www.hnsearch.com/api   'type' seems to be on same level as 'points'...

Comment: @tucson, I got it working with `queries`, but not with `filter`: [http://api.thriftdb.com/api.hnsearch.com/items/_search?pretty_print=true&filter\[fields\]\[create_ts\]=\[NOW-100HOURS TO NOW\]&filter\[fields\]\[points\]=\[20+TO+*\]&filter\[queries\]\[\]=type:"comment"](http://api.thriftdb.com/api.hnsearch.com/items/_search?pretty_print=true&filter%5Bfields%5D%5Bcreate_ts%5D=%5BNOW-100HOURS%20TO%20NOW%5D&filter%5Bfields%5D%5Bpoints%5D=%5B20%20TO%20*%5D&filter%5Bqueries%5D%5B%5D=type:%22comment%22)